# Trouble understanding C style casting the pixels member of a SDL_Surface structure into a (Uint32*)

Tags: c, sdl

I am currently learning SDL. Here is a program that I am trying to understand.

(I cut out a lot of the code, like event polling, to shorten it.)

```
SDL_Surface* backbuffer = NULL;
bool ProgramIsRunning();
void DrawPixel(SDL_Surface *surface, int x, int y, Uint8 r, Uint8 g, Uint8 b);

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    backbuffer = SDL_SetVideoMode(800, 600, 32, SDL_SWSURFACE);

    SDL_WM_SetCaption("Pixel Plot", NULL);

    while(true)
    {
        for(double i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            DrawPixel(backbuffer, rand() % 800, rand() % 600,
                      rand() % 255, rand() % 255, rand() % 255);
        }
        SDL_Flip(backbuffer);
    }
    SDL_Quit();
}

void DrawPixel(SDL_Surface *surface, int x, int y, Uint8 r, Uint8 g, Uint8 b)
{
    if(x >= surface->w || y >= surface->h)
    {
        return;
    }

    Uint32 color = SDL_MapRGB(surface->format, r, g, b);

    Uint32* buffer = (Uint32*)surface->pixels + y * surface->pitch / 4 + x;

    (*buffer) = color;
}
```

The problem for me is this line:

```
buffer = (Uint32*)surface->pixels + y * surface->pitch / 4 + x;
```

I read this line as, take all this stuff, evaluate it, cast it into a pointer to a 32 bit integer, (A memory address containing the 32 bit integer that all the stuff evaluated to) and finally give that memory address to buffer.

So buffer now points to a memory address containing a 32 bit integer, right?

Now, what really stumps me is that the program just immediately overwrites that value with Uint32 color.

So, then what is the point of casting all of that stuff and storing it in buffer?

What effect does the problematic line even have on the program, seeing as it doesn't work without it?

Comment: C and C++ are **different** languages. Don't use invalid tags. This looks like C, if you compile as C++, **change** to C++. Also do not use homebrew fixed-width types! C provides a standard header for this with `stdint.h`. Also note the distributive law is not universal. Specifically a cast does not follow it, even **iff** used on a parenthetised expression. Please read about operator preceedence, this is vital!

Comment: I copied this code out of my book, it's a very early chapter. I don't know what a homebrew fixed-width type is. "A cast does not follow it." What is 'it'?

Comment: 1) Get a new book, yours is >16 years behind. 2) A good start if you don't know a phrase is to look it up after thinking what it could mean. 3) Context is the preceeding sentence.

Comment: My book was published in 2015, it's just still using SDL 1.2 and I did look up 'fixed-width type', but I really can't understand most of the info that's available online about a lot of programming related stuff. Maybe i'm just stupid. I read things over and over and over again, but it still doesn't make sense the tenth (or hundredth) time i've read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
Uint32* buffer = (Uint32*)surface->pixels + y * surface->pitch / 4 + x;
```

Defines a variable of type `Uint32*` and assigns to it the value of the above expression.  The expression casts `surface->pixels` to `Uint32*` and adds an offset to it.  So `buffer` points to some location inside of `surface->pixels`.

This line:

```
(*buffer) = color;
```

Dereferences `buffer` and assigns `color` to the dereferenced pointer.  In other words, the value of `color` is placed at the memory location `buffer` points to.  `buffer` is not being overwritten.  What `buffer` points to is.

Comment: Ok, so what you're saying is that only surface->pixels is actually cast into a  Uint32 and then the rest is added to it?

Comment: @the Correct.  The result is a pointer that points somewhere inside `surface->pixels`.

Comment: Okay, so i'm casting `surface->pixels` into a **pointer** to Uint32, right? That's what the asterisk in (Uint32*) means? So will it become a memory address, or the value stored in the memory address location? Am I offsetting the memory address by adding a random number to it, or am I offsetting the 32 bit integer stored at that memory address?

Comment: Oh crap, I totally get it now! `(Uint32*)surface->pixels` is the memory location that i'm writing `Uint32 color` to.